# Connecting solidwork to labview, occuring runtime error

Tags: runtime-error, labview, solidworks

I am trying to connect solidwork with labview with this tutorial

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0384hrc0B1Q

But at 0:18 where I have to create a new solid assembly I get a "Runtime Error"

http://forums.ni.com/ni/attachments/ni/170/777068/1/error1.png

Is it because I installed it wrong?

-Solidwork 2011 x64

-SoftMotion 2013

-LabView 2012 x84

Or is there another reason?

Comment: My guess is that you need to use Solidworks x86 for it to work.